# I cant import sklearn in Anaconda 2.3.0

Tags: python, linux, scikit-learn, anaconda

I have the newest Anaconda 2.3 on a non-network-Linux-machine. Everything works fine besides
    import sklearn
I then get back

```
----> 1 import sklearn

sklearn.py in <module>()

ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

I have to go into the /pkgs folder in anaconda and into scikit-learn to import from there. This works and whats even weirder, when I type
import
and the tabulator to show possible packages, sklearn is shown.

Comment: Every other package I tried to import worked btw

Comment: If you type `conda list | grep "scikit-learn"`, does it find the package?

Comment: Yes, it gives          scikit-learn              0.15.2               np19py27_0

Answer (score 2):

Might be that you're using another Python installation on your computer.

For instance, I have Python in my Anaconda environement and the other one by default. If execute: `~/anaconda/bin/python` I can import sklearn without problems.

On the contrary if I execute `/usr/bin/python` and then try to export it I get the error message since I installed sklearn from Anaconda.

Check your PATH variable with typing `$PATH` on your terminal and check the order, if Anaconda is not the first one (or it's not there) type: `export PATH="/path/to/anaconda/bin:$PATH"`

I hope this works.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! Unfortunetly i did this before and it's not the case very mysterious because other packages that are only on my Anaconda (like theano) work.